# How can I get the correct element to overflow?

Tags: html, css

I want the `<div class="tags>` elements contents to cause overflow so that one can scroll its contents.
Right now the element simply extends in height when i add more tags/child elements. How can i prevent this?

I've tried many combinations of `overflow-y: scroll` and `min-height: 0` but I don't think I really understand what is happening here. Why does it behave the way it does?

```css
.card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  background: lightskyblue;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}
.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
.customerAvatar {
  background: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.ownerAvatar {
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
.details {
  display: grid;
  flex-grow: 1;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template: 4fr 1fr / 1fr 1fr;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
}
.caseContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
}
.tags {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.tag {
  background: lightcoral;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 2px;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.75rem;
  max-width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
input,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  font: inherit;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 3px;
}

textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: rgb(47, 147, 241);
  border-radius: 3px;
}

input::placeholder,
textarea::placeholder {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: -2px 0px 0px 0px rgba(47, 147, 241, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="customerAvatar"></div>
    <div class="ownerAvatar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="details">
    <div class="caseContainer">
      <input name="case" id="case" placeholder="Case tags" />
      <div class="tags">
        <div class="tag">AAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
        <div class="tag">BBBBBb</div>
        <div class="tag">CCC</div>
        <div class="tag">D</div>
        <div class="tag">FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <textarea name="profilert" id="profilert" placeholder="Profilert"></textarea>
    <input name="dato_frist" id="dato_frist" placeholder="Dato - Frist"></input>
    <input name="kontakt" id="kontakt" placeholder="Kontakt"></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for that you can  specify a max-height to its parent element

Comment: How should I do that? I want everything to be relative to the height and width of the "root"(card) element.

Comment: the default behavior of an element is to size the height according to the content. As such the element can't overflow. To cause an overflow, the element needs either a `fixed height` or `max-height`.

Comment: We can use `flex: auto` to take the available space. then `overflow: auto` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean by?

I used `display: flex` and `flex:auto` to stretch the container as needed.

```css
.card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  background: lightskyblue;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
.customerAvatar {
  background: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.ownerAvatar {
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
.details {
  display: grid;
  flex-grow: 1;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template: 4fr 1fr / 1fr 1fr;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
}
.caseContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex: auto;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.tags {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
.tag {
  background: lightcoral;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 2px;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.75rem;
  max-width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
input,
textarea {
  min-width: 100%;
  align-self: flex-start;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  font: inherit;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 3px;
}

textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: rgb(47, 147, 241);
  border-radius: 3px;
}

input::placeholder,
textarea::placeholder {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: -2px 0px 0px 0px rgba(47, 147, 241, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="customerAvatar"></div>
    <div class="ownerAvatar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="details">
    <div class="caseContainer">
      <input name="case" id="case" placeholder="Case tags" />
      <div class="tags">
        <div class="tag">AAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
        <div class="tag">BBBBBb</div>
        <div class="tag">CCC</div>
        <div class="tag">D</div>
        <div class="tag">FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <textarea name="profilert" id="profilert" placeholder="Profilert"></textarea>
    <input name="dato_frist" id="dato_frist" placeholder="Dato - Frist"></input>
    <input name="kontakt" id="kontakt" placeholder="Kontakt"></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I specified a specific height to its parent element (100px)

Then added height of 90% to your scrolling element.

Reason i used 90% is because the scrollbar's height might overlap the other elements.

this way , your scroll element's height is relative to your parent element.

```css
.card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  border-radius:10px;
}
.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
.customerAvatar {
  background: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.ownerAvatar {
  background: #e52d27;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
.details {
  display: grid;
  flex-grow: 1;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template: 4fr 1fr / 1fr 1fr;
  
}
.caseContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  height:100px;
}
.tags {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height:90%;
}
.tag {
  background: lightcoral;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 2px;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.75rem;
  max-width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
input,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  font: inherit;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 3px;
}

textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: rgb(47, 147, 241);
  border-radius: 3px;
}

input::placeholder,
textarea::placeholder {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: -2px 0px 0px 0px rgba(47, 147, 241, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="customerAvatar"></div>
    <div class="ownerAvatar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="details">
    <div class="caseContainer">
      <input name="case" id="case" placeholder="Case tags" />
      <div class="tags">
        <div class="tag">AAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
        <div class="tag">BBBBBb</div>
        <div class="tag">CCC</div>
        <div class="tag">D</div>
        <div class="tag">FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <textarea name="profilert" id="profilert" placeholder="Profilert"></textarea>
    <input name="dato_frist" id="dato_frist" placeholder="Dato - Frist"></input>
    <input name="kontakt" id="kontakt" placeholder="Kontakt"></input>
  </div>
</div>
```